# Compiler options to python setup.py

Tags: python, cython, intel, distutils

I have a Python package that requires compiling some C (cython) and fortran (f2py) code. I would like to give the user the freedom to use GNU or Intel compilers. Currently, the following works for me

```
python setup.py build_ext -i --fcompiler=intelem --compiler=intelem # on the intel system
python setup.py build_ext -i # on the GNU system
```

for in-place importing. However, I would also like this to be achievable when the user installs as

```
python setup.py install --user
```

This usually calls `build_ext` first. However, passing arguments like this

```
python setup.py install --user --fcompiler=intelem --compiler=intelem
```

is not allowed. `setup.py` complains that `fcompiler` and `compiler` are unrecognized arguments. How can I provide these arguments to the `build_ext` part of `install`?

Comment: Why not ask the user to set the environment variables `CC` and `FC` before hand? `setup.py` will then detect the compiler properly. You can test which compiler is used  by calling `os.environ["CC"]` within your `setup.py`.

Comment: I've tried that. distutils doesn't seem to respect those variables. It explicitly needs those flags to use the intel compilers.